# Twitter bootstrap label with <br>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I have a double line in a label without breaking the label itself?

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Khrys/7AKvM/133/

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Example heading <span class="label label-default">What´s<br>New</span></h1>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just give the label `display: inline-block;`.

[**Working Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/7AKvM/134/)

Comment: I agree that this solution works. I am curious why this is a span tag however. If it's to look like a button I might suggest using the bootstrap button classes